# FXML ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

## Error

```
C:\Users\rbenedict\Documents\Java Modules>java -cp .;fxmltut fxmltut.FXMLEx
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(Unk
nown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(Unknown Sou
rce)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(Unknown So
urce)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(
Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException:
/C:/Users/rbenedict/Documents/Java%20Modules/fxmltut/FXMLDoc.fxml

        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.importClass(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processImport(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processProcessingInstruction(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source)
        at fxmltut.FXMLEx.start(FXMLEx.java:17)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162
(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(Unknown
 Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(Unknown Sourc
e)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(Unknown S
ource)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(Unknown Source)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadType(Unknown Source)
        ... 21 more
Exception running application fxmltut.FXMLEx
```

I tried with and without package `fxmltut`. Without I get the same exception and did some checking online.  Apparently, javafx parses the import statement by looking for the `.` token and taking the identifier after.  So I made it part of a package and I am still getting the same error.

## FXMLEx.java

```
package fxmltut;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import javafx.scene.Parent;
import java.lang.Class;

import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;

public class FXMLEx extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDoc.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300,275);

        stage.setTitle("FXML Welcome");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

## FXMLCont.java

```
package fxmltut;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;

public class FXMLCont {
    @FXML private Text actTarg;
    @FXML protected void handleSubmitButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        actTarg.setText("Sign in button pressed");
    }
}
```

## FXMLDoc.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import fxmltut.*?>
<?import java.net.*?>
<?import java.geometry.*?>
<?import java.scene.control*?>
<?import java.scene.layout.*?>
<?import java.scene.text.*?>

<GridPane fx:controller="fxmltut.FXMLCont"

    xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" alignment="center" hgap="10" vgap="10">
    <padding><Insets top="25" right="25" bottom="25" left="25"/></padding>

</GridPane>

<Text text="Welcome"
    GridePane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="0"
    GridPane.columnSpan="2"/>

<Label text="User Name:"
    GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="1"/>
<TextField
    GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1"/>

<Label text="Password:"
    GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="2"/>

<PasswordField fx:id="pw" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2"/>

<HBox spacing="10" alignment = "bottom_right"
    GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="4">

    <Button text="Sign in"
    onAction="#handleSubmitButtonAction"/>

</HBox>

<Text fx:id="actTarg"
    GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.columnSpan="2"
    GridPane.halignment="RIGHT" GridPane.rowIndex="6" />
```

Comment: Please post the full stacktrace.

Comment: And while you're at it: Fix that fxml - It's not well-formed!

Comment: @hotzst Full stack trace added now.
No idea how to make a well formed fxml :(  It was my first xml file and I did it like these guys.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/get-started-tutorial/fxml_tutorial.htm

Comment: The same way you'd make any other XML file well-formed given that text: By ensuring there is a single root element. Since you seem to be adding everything as children of the `GridPane`, move the closing tag of the `GridPane` element to the very end of the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first you should check that FXML file could be loaded.  `getClass().getResource("FXMLDoc.fxml")` must be not null and must provide no Exception.

At second, as @fabian already have said, your FXML is ill-formed. It must contain only one **root** tag as any other XML.

Comment: Thank you!  I'll check into more FXML rules since I'm not all that familiar with it.  I just assumed there was a problem finding the fxml file since it couldn't load the class... So if I check for that, then I would know if it could find it versus could load it.  Then I can know if it is a format problem.

Answer (score 2):

Your FXML has invalid format. You should have all nodes in GridPane container.

Like fabian said in comments ensure there is a single root element.

Try to put code simple as below and see if application is running. If it is, then it was incorrectly defined fxml file layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>

<GridPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="377.0" prefWidth="533.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" fx:controller="fxmltut.FXMLCont">

</GridPane>
```