# FXML load issue

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

Working on learning how fxml works.

Following a [java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/get-started-tutorial/fxml_tutorial.htm) I wrote a simple program that won't seem to load my fxml file.

Since this fails to load, I think there is an issue with my GridPane set up.  I thought it was correct based on section 6-3 of that tutorial.

I also followed the advice of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36226933/2415237) and ran this fxml document and I received no error and a white unformatted box did appear. I tried adjusting the xmlns:fx variable to be `http://javafx.com/fxml/1` but it didn't change the outcome.

## Error

```
C:\Users\rbenedict\Documents\Java Modules>java -cp .;fxmltut fxmltut.FXMLEx
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(Unk
nown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(Unknown Sou
rce)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(Unknown So
urce)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(
Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException:
/C:/Users/rbenedict/Documents/Java%20Modules/fxmltut/FXMLDoc.fxml

        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.importClass(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processImport(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processProcessingInstruction(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source)
        at fxmltut.FXMLEx.start(FXMLEx.java:24)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162
(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(Unknown
 Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(Unknown Sourc
e)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(Unknown S
ource)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(Unknown Source)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadType(Unknown Source)
        ... 16 more
Exception running application fxmltut.FXMLEx
```

## FXMLEx.java

```
package fxmltut;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import javafx.scene.Parent;
import java.lang.Class;

import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;

public class FXMLEx extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {


        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("FXMLDoc.fxml"));
        if(loader == null) {
            System.out.println("Can't find fxml!");
            System.exit(1); 

        }
        Parent root = loader.load();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300,275);

        stage.setTitle("FXML Welcome");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

## FXMLCont

```
package fxmltut;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;

public class FXMLCont {
    @FXML private Text actTarg;
    @FXML protected void handleSubmitButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        actTarg.setText("Sign in button pressed");
    }
}
```

## FXMLDoc.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import fxmltut.*?>
<?import java.net.*?>
<?import java.geometry.*?>
<?import java.scene.control*?>
<?import java.scene.layout.*?>
<?import java.scene.text.*?>

<GridPane fx:controller="fxmltut.FXMLCont"

    xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" alignment="center" hgap="10" vgap="10">
    <padding><Insets top="25" right="25" bottom="25" left="25"/></padding>

   <!--

    <Text text="Welcome"
        GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="0"
        GridPane.columnSpan="2"/>

    <Label text="User Name:"
        GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="1"/>
    <TextField
        GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1"/>

    <Label text="Password:"
        GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="2"/>

    <PasswordField fx:id="pw" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2"/>

    <HBox spacing="10" alignment = "bottom_right"
        GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="4">

        <Button text="Sign in"
        onAction="#handleSubmitButtonAction"/>

    </HBox>

    <Text fx:id="actTarg"
        GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.columnSpan="2"
        GridPane.halignment="RIGHT" GridPane.rowIndex="6" />
    -->
</GridPane>
```

## Working FXML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>

<GridPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="377.0" prefWidth="533.0" 
xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" fx:controller="fxmltut.FXMLCont">

</GridPane>
```

## EDIT

Woops, forgot to indent the import statements when I pasted fxml contents.  Made the lines disappear.  Strange.

Comment: In your FXML that isn't working - you didn't show the imports at the top.  Since the stack trace is a class not found, I just wanted to ask if you had those imports there?

Comment: @ManoDestra This comment answers the question and should be an Answer.

Comment: Woops, Had the import statements there, just didn't show up since I didn't have them preceded by 4 spaces.  Import statements are included and still I get the issue.

Comment: NOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO.  I SEE IT NOW THOUGH

Comment: those should be javafx import statements not java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, if your FXML is definitely on the classpath and valid, then you should be fine, but it looks like it's missing import statements. You should also be checking that your resource does not come back as null, prior to your FXMLLoader null check. You could perhaps just use the static FXMLLoader.load method rather than instantiating an FXMLLoader object. Or perhaps a try-catch block, at least.

EDIT: now that you've amended your import statements, they are pointing at java., etc, rather than javafx. Should be like this...

```
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your imports are not correct on the FXML file:

```
<?import java.geometry.*?>
<?import java.scene.control*?>
<?import java.scene.layout.*?>
<?import java.scene.text.*?>
```

Become

```
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
```